# Backbone and dot.js

Tags: backbone.js, dot.js

I am new to both backbone and dot.js. I need help in integrating external dot.js file in to my backbone file.

My backbone file looks like

```
 success :function() {

    SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
      template: doT.template(dotView(id,fullurl)),

      initialize: function() {
            _.bindAll(this);
            this.render();
      },

      render: function() {      
        this.$el.html(this.template({data: data.entries}));
      }         
    });

    var search_view = new SearchView({ el: $("#search_container") });       

  }
```

where in "dot.Template" I am calling dotView which is present in dot.js file. This method is working fine but I want to impliment it using ajax.

my dot.js file looks like

```
function dotView(id,fullurl){
    temp = "{{~ it.data :value }}{{ if (check('{{=value.guid}}') == true) { }}<p>{{= value.title}}</p><p>{{= value.author}}</p><p>{{= value.description}}</p>";
    temp = temp + "{{~ it.data :value }}{{~ value.media$content :video}} {{ if (bitrate('{{= video.plfile$bitrate}}') == true) { }} {{ trigger_video(video.plfile$url); }} {{ } }} {{~}}{{~}}{{ } }}{{~}}";
    temp = temp + "<br/><div><b>See More:</b></div>{{~ it.data :value }}{{ if (check('{{=value.guid}}') != true) { }}{{~ value.media$thumbnails :photo}} {{ if (compare('{{=photo.plfile$width}}') == true) { }}<a href='details.html?id={{=value.guid}}&feed={{=fullurl}}'><img src='{{=photo.plfile$url}}' width='80' height='60'></img></a> {{ } }} {{~}} {{ } }}{{~}}";
    return temp;
}
```

Please help in this

Answer (score 0):

[RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) is recommended, it has a [!text](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#text) plugin. let you store your template in a text file. And requireJS will load it asynchronizely when you "require" it.